# Kronecker Delta and Contraction in Feyncalc

Tags: code-request, feyncalc

I am trying to simplify a rather complicated equation involving vectors and kronecker delta. I am trying to use Feyncalc for this purpose, but somehow i am not able to do it using Contract/Trick.

Could some one help me ?

A simple thing like KroneckerDelta[u,v] FV[x,v] is also not giving be the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing things that don't belong together. `KroneckerDelta` is a built-in Mathematica object, while `FV` is FeynCalc's shortcut for a Lorentz 4-vector. FeynCalc's `Contract` naturally works only with FeynCalc objects.

If you want to use FeynCalc for your purposes, you should write `MT[u,v]` instead. Since FeynCalc doesn't distinguish between upper and lower Lorentz indices, Kronecker delta and Minkowski metric are essentially represented by the same object.

```
Contract[MT[u, v] FV[x, v]]
```

returns the correct result.

Comment: Great catch; +1